# Recursive economy with uncertainty in two islands

Tags: macroeconomics, self-study, recursive-macroeconomics

There are two economies A and B with infinitely many identical households. Since there are infinitely many identical households in each economy, they are all price taker. Maeasure of agents in A and B are equal. Agent preference is a follows

$$\sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \beta^t u(c_t)$$

The only difference between countries A and B is the production technology for $i=A,B$ $$y=z^if(k)$$

The final gods produced are identical for both technologies and capital depreciates fully. Let $z=(z^A,z^B)$ and $z$ follows chain state Markov process of order one and denote the probability that $z’$ occurs conditional in z $\Gamma_{zz’}$.

**Part a** assume that there is no trade between two island and write down the recursive problem of one type with complete market (that is, with state contingent claim $b_{z’}$

**Part b** assume that both capital and goods are perfectly mobile across islands without any cost. That is, households can rent their capital to firms in any country depending on the rate of return they  get. So, write down the recursive problem of one type with complete market (that is, with state contingent claim $b_{z’}$

**Part c** let us assume that technology is linear in capital $f(k)=k$. There is restriction on the movement of capital but not on goods. Assume that there is state contingent claim trade across islands. How can we interpret the welfare loss of this restriction on capital compared to a world without one.

Please can you share hints of this question for each part. I will improve my answer and then I will share it here.

I don’t want you to solve for whole questions. I have some points on the parts which I want you to explain. Please discuss this question with me.

In part a,

The question states there is no trade. Therefore, will I omit the state contingent trade?

That is, the bellman equation is

$$V^i(z^i, K^i, a^i)=max \{ u(c^i)+\beta \sum_{z’} \Gamma_{zz’} V^i(z’^i, K’^i, a’^i)$$

Such that

$$c^i+a’^i= w^i+r^i a^i$$

Let us look at the part b. However, what happens (what changes) if we consider both capital and goods are perfectly mobile across islands without any cos in the bellman equation?

Does I include the state contingent claim?

$$V^i(z^i, K^i, a^i, b^i)=\max \{ u(c^i)+\beta \sum_{z’} \Gamma_{zz’} V^i(z’^i, K’^i, a’^i, b_z’^i)\}$$

$$c^i+a’^i + \sum q_z b_z’^i= w^i+r^i a^i +b^i$$

And I have no idea on part c.

Note that $w$ is wage, $r$ is rate of return , $x’$ is the one forward state of the variable. That $x_t=x$ and $x_{t+1}=x’$

Comment: That is, please explain which variable I will add or remove or change according to the description in each part. Many thanks.